# jmeter.functions error: jexl.parser.ParseException: Encountered "{"

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I use jmeter for loading test. I specify the "Thread Group" as "${__jexl(${LoadRatio}*1,)}". and I meet the error below. What is wrong?

```
2015/10/14 15:36:25 ERROR - jmeter.functions.JexlFunction: An error occurred while evaluating the expression "${LoadRatio}*1"
```

org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ParseException: Encountered "{" at line 1, column 2.
Was expecting one of:
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "|" ...
    "^" ...
    "&" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "ne" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<=" ...
    "le" ...
    ">=" ...
    "ge" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "div" ...
    "%" ...
    "mod" ...
    ";" ...
    "[" ...
    "." ...
    "=" ...

```
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.Parser.generateParseException(Parser.java:4176)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.Parser.jj_consume_token(Parser.java:4043)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.Parser.ExpressionExpression(Parser.java:1885)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.Parser.Statement(Parser.java:1858)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.Parser.JexlScript(Parser.java:73)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:32)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.ScriptFactory.createNewScript(ScriptFactory.java:162)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.ScriptFactory.createScript(ScriptFactory.java:99)
at org.apache.jmeter.functions.JexlFunction.execute(JexlFunction.java:79)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:142)
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:118)
at kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroupGui.refreshPreview(SteppingThreadGroupGui.java:240)
at kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroupGui.modifyTestElement(SteppingThreadGroupGui.java:263)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.updateCurrentNode(GuiPackage.java:436)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getCurrentGui(GuiPackage.java:272)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory.addFileMenu(MenuFactory.java:224)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.AbstractThreadGroupGui.createPopupMenu(AbstractThreadGroupGui.java:82)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeNode.createPopupMenu(JMeterTreeNode.java:158)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.EditCommand.doAction(EditCommand.java:47)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that your `LoadRatio` variable is not defined.